# How do I align sorting images in table headers to right

Tags: css

[Current State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsmGJ.png)

How do I get it right next to header without any spacings ?
`<th><img class="waves-effect waves-light" src="../assets/sorting.png" style="text-align: right; padding-right: 0">address</th>`
 I have tried this but did not help.Any idea on what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear, but if you're meaning how to move the sorting images to the right of the th, just move the img to the right of the th.

```html
<th>address<img class="waves-effect waves-light" src="../assets/sorting.png" style="text-align: right; padding-right: 0"></th>
```

(Obviously I don't have sorting.png for my example, but you get the idea.)

Answer (score 1):

In CSS, you can use
 text-align: right; 
And you can reduce padding to none with 
Padding-right: 0;

Comment: `<th><img class="waves-effect waves-light"                                                                                    src="../assets/sorting.png" style="text-align: right; padding-right: 0">address</th>`

I have tried this but did not help.Any idea on what's going wrong?
Appreciate your help.